# Platform-independent Python call from Jenkinsfile

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile that looks like this:

```
stage('MyStage') {
  steps {
    script {
      bat script: "python my-script.py"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want this Jenkinsfile to be able to also run on a Linux machine, and since this line "python my-script.py", can be executed exactly the same way in both Windows and Linux I want to find a way to **not** duplicate the call like this:

```
if (isUnix()) {
  sh: "python my-script.py"
} else {
  bat: "python my-script.py"
}
```

Is it possible to solve this in a pretty way?

Thanks!

/klarre

Comment: If you're doing this repeatedly, just write a function to do it.

Comment: If docker can be an option, you can try run that cmd by docker, and with docker it can provide a python environment, rather than to prepare python environment in advance on each jenkins worker node.

Comment: @NickBailey You mean something like this? See my last post.

Answer (score 0):

```
def call(string cmd) {
    if (isUnix()) {
        sh: cmd
    } else {
        bat: cmd
    }
}

stage('MyStage') {
  steps {
    script {
      call("python my-script.py")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some human explanation of your solution, please ? that would be great : ) easier to understand